# Retrieve SQL statement from MySQL and process in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have successfully saved a number of SQL UPDATE statements to MySQL and now I want to retrieve them and have PHP process them. The code is below.

When I echo $query I get the correct SQL statements from the DB, but then when I try to process them, I get an error Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query

It makes no sense to me and is driving me nuts! Do I have to do something else to $query so PHP can process it?

```
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($resultSQL);
if ($num_rows > 0)
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSQL))
        {
            $strSQLupd[] = $row['uSQL'];
        }
        foreach ($strSQLupd as $query) {
            $resultSQLupd = mysqli_query($link, 
            $query
            );
            if (!$resultSQLupd)
            {
                $error = 'Error fetching data: ' . mysqli_error($link);
                include 'error.html.php';
                exit();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you try var_dump($strSQLupd) and see if it is being set properly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the value of $link somewhere and is it required for what you're doing in this application?  Also, remember that `var_dump($varname);` is always a helpful debugging tool.

```
    foreach ($strSQLupd as $query) {
        // put a var_dump below
        var_dump($query);
        $resultSQLupd = mysqli_query($query
        );
        if (!$resultSQLupd)
        {
            $error = 'Error fetching data: ' . mysqli_error($link);
            include 'error.html.php';
            exit();
        }
    }
```

Give this a shot and look at the query string dumped to the screen.  It may be null which is what's producing your error.

Comment: I put in var_dump and get string(0) "", which clearly means the string is empty. So, 2 questions ... (1) How do I fix that; and (2) Why does the echo work?

Comment: Ah-ha ... I found the problem. As usual, it was in some other piece of code. The data I was retrieving had some NULL values in it. So, echo works but there was no SQL for PHP to process. The var-dump helped find the problem, so a big thank you ;)

Comment: @user2042038 That's awesome!  I am glad it helped you find the issue. I use variable dumps all the time in development.  Of course doing this is no substitute for using an actual debugger but it's a quick way to get a visualization of your data.

Comment: In the last sentence of my answer I suggested a null query string may be causing the error. + for me! ;0